# How can I compare a .zip's files to the non zip version?

Tags: diff

I'm using 7-zip.

I want to compare a huge backup Zip file (200GB) to the unzipped files.
(I'm guessing the files are the same, but want to make sure without unzipping 200 GB)

I've tried using Beyond Compare 3  but it claims the .zip files isn't valid. (It is b/c I can open it in 7-zip.

**Will CRC(file.zip) = CRC (unzipped (file.zip))?**
I can calculate a CRC has on the .zip, but don't know if a CRC of a .zip does the CRC on the *contents* or the .zip itself.
I my very simple test, these CRC values were **not** equal.

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely the CRC32 of the file, not the archived data:

[image: CRC]

And that's how your archive manager determines if your files are corrupted. So, if testing the archive suggested a corrupted file (or set of files) then it means the hash of the file after extraction, doesn't correspond to the stored hash value for the file before archiving.